# Generate thumbnail for a bunch of mp4 video in a folder

Tags: php, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107710/create-video-thumbnail-of-all-files-in-a-directory-via-ffmpeg-and-php) but didnt help too much.

I have a folder called **videos** and another folder called **thumbnails**. I have many mp4 videos in video folder and want to catch thumbnails at 4th second to the thumbnails folder using ffmpeg and php.

1. I am using Wamp server 2.2 on windows whit php 5.3.8 and Apache 2.2.21
2. I downloaded ffmpeg from **FFmpeg Windows Builds** section of [ffmpeg download page](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) and the static 32 build from [this](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/win32/static/ffmpeg-latest-win32-static.7z) link.
3. I extracted the 7z file to my website root
   here is my php code:

   ```
   $ffmpeg = "includes/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
   foreach(glob('files/videos/*.mp4') as $pathname){
     $filename = substr($pathname,13,strripos($pathname,'.mp4')-13);
     $thumbnail = 'files/thumbnails/'.$filename.'.jpg';
     exec("ffmpeg -i $pathname -an -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:04 -vframes 1 $thumbnail");
   }
   ```

but nothing happens and the thumbnails folder is always empty!
- How can I find out is ffmpeg installed on my server or not?
- How can I get my script to work?
Please help

Comment: Can you check permissions and path is defined properly?

Comment: @DoSparKot what permissions? I am using wamp server and I have windows folders. I have everyone full access to videos and thumbnails. but nothing changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
$ffmpeg = "c:/wamp/www/includes/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
$videos = "c:/wamp/www/files/videos/*.mp4";
$ouput_path = "c:/wamp/www/files/thumbnails/";
foreach(glob($videos) as $v_file){
    $fname = basename($v_file, ".mp4");
    $thmb = $ouput_path.$fname.'_tn.jpg';
    $cmd = "$ffmpeg -i $v_file -an -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:04 -vframes 1 $thmb";
    $stat = system ($cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with absolute paths in commands instead of depending on PATH ENV variable:
Both `exec()` and `system()` works. Resolve the path definitions.

```
/* Using Absolute paths */
$ffmpeg = "c:/wamp/www/includes/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg";
$videos = "c:/wamp/www/files/videos/*.mp4";
$ouput_path = "c:/wamp/www/files/thumbnails/";

foreach(glob($videos) as $video_file){

    $filename = basename($video_file, ".mp4");
    $thumbnail = $ouput_path.$filename.'_tn.jpg';
    $command = "$ffmpeg -i $video_file -an -y -f mjpeg -ss 00:00:04 -vframes 1 $thumbnail";

    $status = system ($command);
/*or
    $status = exec($command);

    if ($status === false) {
        var_dump("ERROR: Conversion Failed!!!!");
    } else
        var_dump($status);
*/
}
```

Comment: Interesting, can you put single file in `C:\temp\` and try with modified paths?

Comment: It depends on the internal constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR it's / in code and outputs `\\` for windows platforms.

Comment: @PedarJepeto anyways, thanks to you, now I know how to generate thumbnails of videos on the fly. :-)

Comment: does it really work for you? I exactly copy and paste the code but can not get it to work!! :(

Answer (score 0):

I´m not allowed to add a comment, so here (as a Post) is what I found out while dealing with this: 
The white space in the file name prevents ffmpeg from finding the right file. So one way is to change the file name.

Comment: The `ffmpeg` cli tool handles spaces just fine with proper quoting or escaping: `ffmpeg -i input "output 1.mp4" 'output 2.mp4' output\ 3.mp4`

Comment: Thanks, I´ll try that

Comment: I'm not a PHP user (the question is tagged [tag:php]), so my three examples may or may not work for PHP.

Comment: Oh, it worked just fine, I used the "output 1.mp4" escaping the quotes, in the string, like this: - \"output 1.mp4\" - and voila!!! :) thanks for the tip, I believe this is the reason that it wasn´t working for Pedar Jepeto.